# Mantis - How to get all email notifications including own actions?

Tags: mantis

We are using Mantis 1.1.2.

Whenever a user makes changes in the system, you get an email notification automatically.

However if I myself make changes to the system, everyone gets the notification email except the one editing it, in this case myself.

I searched for the notification settings but did not find anything.

How to enable the email notification also for actions done by myself?

Comment: http://www.mantisbt.org/support.php

Comment: @ceejayoz - that's not extremely helpful ... there are people offering support for MantisBT here as well, as you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `$g_email_receive_own = ON;` in your config_inc.php file.

Source: [MantisBT administration guide, email section](http://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master-1.2.x/en/administration_guide/admin.config.email.html) .

Comment: Thanks I will ask the admin for it. Can this also be set only for some users?